# ISP only allows one mac adress at a time, how to share internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I am at an university residence, and the internet provider company only allows only one connection per account, while providing me internet only through a RJ45 ethernet connection.Each time a new device is plugged in through ethernet I need to log in a webpage. I tried using a router airport extreme plugging in the ethernet to create a wifi network, but it does not allow me to share the internet by WiFi, because I need to login in the webpage of the ISP whenever I use a new device, losing the internet connection in the rest of devices. I think that the ISP just allows only one mac adress at a time.

The only solution I found to have internet in more than one device is to connect the Ethernet to a laptop and then create a wireless hotspot. The problem is that my hotspot has random intermittent issues which I cannot solve.

Do you have any idea on how to create a wifi network acting like a hotspot simulating that there is only one MAC address connected at the time? Even with a router, such as the airport extreme I have?

Comment: We need to know what method is used by your ISP to login. In order to use a router, the router has to be able to support logging in using that method **in the router itself**. If a "Captive Portal" is used then I don't think using a router will work.

Comment: Does your router have MAC address spoofing?   If so, login via your computer, then connect the router with the MAC set to the same MAC as the computer.  I'm not sure if AirPort Extreme has the feature or not, but most popular routers do.

Answer (score 1):

A router connects several machines to a network but cannot (!) conserve their MAC addresses when transfering the traffic - outward traffic will always carry the router's MAC address. MAC address authentication is used in Europe by cable ISPs in the same way you report your situation. Directly connecting changing hosts will not work without manual re-authentication. Using a router instead solves this.

My suspicion is that you set up the Airport router incorrectly. It can work as a hotspot (as a router) but also as a wireless bridge (as a switch). In the latter case several MAC addresses will be seen on the WAN side.

This is confirmed by your attempts to use your notebook as a WiFi hotspot. This is exactly what an accesspoint is built for, routing several hosts on one port towards another port.

Comment: Thank you your answer. I tried setting the router in bridge mode, but when connecting new device it tells me that I need to login through the ISP webpage with this new device. Whenever I login in this page with the new device, the webpage tells me that only one device can connect at a time to the network, thus disconnecting all of the other devices from accesing the internet. It seems like a security measure to avoid internet sharing... Do you think that there is a way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: As I've posted: bridging will NOT work for this, your router must be set up to ROUTE. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Try to reconfigure it.

Comment: @user3809358 The point is a normal router should already work out of the box. Messing any of the settings such as changing the bridging will expose all the MAC addresses of your devices to the network, which isn't what you would want.

Comment: Correct. I've worked with an Airport and know it could be (mis-)configured as a bridging device, as one of multiple choices when initially configuring it. I just wanted to point out the consequences.